# Component Directive with Template and data bindings

Tags: angular

In Angular2 is it possible to source below out into a directive?

```ts
<button [attr.disabled]="!infoForm.valid"></button>
```

e.g. have later:

```ts
<button [isValid]="!infoForm.valid"></button>
```

#### Edit

Would it be possible to end up with a more complex directive like such:?

```ts
@Component({
    selector: 'isValid',
    template: `
    <div>
        <button primary class="primary" (click)="next($event)">{{title}}</button>
    </div>`
})

export class ContinuationCheckDirective {

    @Input() isValid:boolean = false;

    @HostBinding('attr.disabled')
    disabled: boolean;

    ngOnChanges() {
        this.disabled = !this.isValid;
    }

    next() { // dostuff }
```

And then in parent component:

```ts
 <continuationCheckDirective [isValid]="!addresForm.valid"></continuationCheckDirective>
```

Comment: You would need to change the selector to `continuationCheckDirective`. `[isValid]="..."` would still work because this only needs to match the `@Input()` name. I used the selector `[isValid]` so you don't need to add one attribute to get the directive instantiated and another one to assign to the `@Input()` but instead combined them to one.

Comment: I added a Plunker to my answer. Can you please point out what is not working as expected according to this concrete example?

Comment: Very nice, thanks for that. I forked the plunk showing how the Button should look like when isValid is false. https://plnkr.co/edit/k9p2deZHiS4uSQA1sC3S?p=preview

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/RZX8bEf96XW5bbO6Lo5K?p=preview. The value bound to `disabled` needs to be `null` instead of `false` to get the `disabled` attribute removed. `disabled="false"` is the same as `disabled="true"` or just `disabled`.

Comment: Oh nice how could I miss that. Thanks a lot for you working with me on this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```ts
@Directive({
  selector: '[isValid]'
})
class IsValidDirective {

  @Input() isValid:boolean = false;

  @HostBinding('attr.disabled')
  disabled: boolean;

  ngOnChanges() {
    this.disabled = !this.isValid;
  }
}
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/ddSo1euFPm4ekqSnLfYX?p=preview)

Comment: Very interesting. Would it be possible to do it for the whole button, e.g. have later in Template only: `<myDirective ...></myDirective>`

Comment: Not sure what you mean by this. What is `<myDirective>`

Comment: e.g. mydirective is where the template from the directive-component gets injected.

Comment: I find `directive-component` a bit confusing ;-). You do the same in a component if this is what you want.

Comment: Ok let me try out and update my question in a few minutes

Comment: Getting `Can't bind to 'isValid' since it isn't a known native property`..

Comment: You need to add `IsValidDirective` to the `directives: [...]` of the components where you want to use it or provide it globally using `PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES`. I also forgot the `[]` around the selector in my initial post. You might have missed the update.

Comment: Ok in the simple of both versions, my button is now disabled, but not getting enabled when I switch `infoForm` to true in parent component.